# TidTCPClient expecting reply from TidTCPServer

Tags: delphi-7

I am trying to create a simple TCP client/server application. So, the server will wait for a command from the client. Once the command received, the server will perform some tasks which could take up to 60 seconds. During this time, the TCP client should wait for the result of those tasks.

The sending and receiving of the command have been done using the "WriteLn" and "ReadLn" method.

But, I don't know how to do the "waiting" part for the TCP client. Because I don't see any event in the TidTCPClient that can capture this.

I tried using "ReadLn" with timeout, but it seems doesn't work.

```
  recv := '';
  recv := TCPClient.ReadLn(#0, 30*1000);
```

From the server, before 30 seconds, I sent something:

```
AThread.Connection.WriteLn('SUCCESS');
```

But that has never been received.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I should use this:

```
recv := TCPClient.ReadLn('', 30*1000);
```

Instead of:

```
recv := TCPClient.ReadLn(#0, 30*1000);
```

Then the issue is resolved.

Comment: Setting the `ATerminator` to a blank string tells `ReadLn` to use its default terminator, which is `LF` (which also handles `CRLF`). The alternative is to use the `ReadTimeout` property instead, and don't pass any parameters to `ReadLn()` so it uses its default terminator: `TCPClient.ReadTimeout := 30*1000; recv := TCPClient.ReadLn;`